# search suggest drop down list according to database values in jsp

Tags: function, jsp

I am getting search suggest drop down list Statically but i want it from database

[please see this link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i got the solution [Please check it](http://pastebin.com/kpLaXpzR)

But i am unable to search result according to the starting letter. If any one know the solution please solve

Regards